# How to use CSVLogger in Python

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to run the following code that takes a parkinson's disease dataset and trains a neural network. I want to save the accuracy and loss of the network at each epoch for 10000 epochs. I am using CSVLogger to accomplish this task. The logger saves a csv with three columns: epochs, loss, and accuracy. However, when I inspect the csv after the code runs, the accuracy is the same for each epoch. These are not the same accuracies that print when I run the model itself. How can I get CSVLogger to save the accuracies that print when I run the model?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger

# load the dataset
data = loadtxt('/Users/ciarasikking/Desktop/Research/Python Codes/Parkinsons Data/pd_speech_features.csv', delimiter=',')
data_pd = np.delete(data, [0], 1)
# split into input (X) and output (y) variables

X = data_pd[:,0:753]
y = data_pd[:,753]

# define the keras model
model_pd = Sequential()
model_pd.add(Dense(1, input_dim=753, activation='sigmoid'))
model_pd.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

csv_logger = CSVLogger("Keras_pd_data10000.csv", append=True)

# compile the keras model
model_pd.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model_pd.fit(X, y, epochs=10000, batch_size=10, callbacks=(csv_logger))
```

Picture of csv that CSVLogger produces:
[image: Picture of csv that CSVLogger produces]

Picture of accuracies that print when model runs:
[image: Picture of accuracies that print when model runs:]